# PHP Form Fields with Int as name for json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following code which works well to get specific values and strip the strings like I need. However, I want to grab the fields with an int for the name and place those into an json array under my custom fields section. How can I iterate over the fields and find all fields with an int for the name then use that as the json ID with the passed value as the json value? IE:

```
input type="text" name="24349163" value="Here"
```

JSON encoded:

```
"id"=>'24349163', "value" =>'value of the field I need'
```

What I have now:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match('/^z_/i',$key)){
        $arr[strip_tags($key)] = strip_tags($value);
    }
}
$create = json_encode(array('ticket' => array('subject' => $arr['z_subject'],
'comment' => array( "body"=> $arr['z_description']), 'requester' => 
array('name' => $arr['z_name'], 'email' => $arr['z_requester']), 
'custom_fields' => array("id"=>'24349163', "value" =>'Here'))));
```

Form for post:

```
 <form id="zFormer" method="post" action="tickets.php" name="zFormer">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="z_name">Your Name:</label>
     <input type="text" value="John Doe" name="z_name" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="z_requester">Your Email Address: </label>
     <input type="text" value="john@domain.com" name="z_requester" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="z_subject">Title/Subject: </label>
     <input type="text" value="Who needs a subject?" name="z_subject" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="z_description">Summary Description:</label> 
     <textarea name="z_description">Systems are down</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="24275273">Incident Start Date:</label><br/> 
     <input type="date" name="24275273" value="" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="24275293">Incident Start Time:</label><br/> 
     <input type="time" name="24275293" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok so when you have multiple like that, when you assign the array, you will have the array save as:  `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][0] = array..etc.` and `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][1] = etc.`. To read the array back, you would loop through `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields']`

Comment: You don't assign the `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][0]` manually, that is what the `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][]` does. It's the same as `array_push()`

Comment: Ive tried that several times and getting the php error back. When I try the following I get just the word array but not values. I have to use the index to get each one. How can I do this to show the actual values for each array stored values? 

    foreach($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][] as $val) {
        print $val;
    }

Comment: Close, should be `foreach($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'] as $val) { print_r($val); }`

Comment: This would allow you to do `echo $val['id'];` and `echo $val['value'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question, but it *sounds* like you need to add an else in your `foreach`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match('/^z_/i',$key)){
        $arr[strip_tags($key)] = strip_tags($value);
    }
    elseif(is_numeric($key)) {
        $arr['ticket']['custom_fields'] =   array('id'=>$key,'value'=>$value);
        /*
        if you expect multiple id values:
        $arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][]   =   array('id'=>$key,'value'=>$value);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer a little better as it creates what i need for the custom fields im building. So  would use the $arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][] to list all of the fields comma separated correct? Its been a while since using php so i apologize for the silliness of the question.

Comment: If you have multiple `int` key/values that you want to store in the json array, then you use `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][]`.

Comment: If you only want just the one `array(id=>123123123,'value'=>'Whatever the value was')` then you use just `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields']`

Comment: getting Cannot use [] for reading error in php when calling the array now?

Comment: Correct, you can not read an array with that, you assign it that way, and when it saves to your array, the keys are list numerically as `[0]`,`[1]` etc.

Comment: If you only have one `int` name in your form, just use the `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields']`

Comment: Can you post an example of your form example? I could give you better direction if I saw what you currently have to generate the `$_POST`

Comment: ok, but I want to dump the full list in my create section. IE: 'custom_fields' => array($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][])  is that possible?

Comment: Its too long for comments, can I post somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, just do `EDIT:` in your question, at the bottom then paste there.

Comment: If you give me your email and send me your script I can take a couple minutes out to help you since you are still having issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is processing only $*POST keys that start with z*. To fix, use this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match('/^z_/i',$key) || gettype($key) == 'integer'){
    $arr[strip_tags($key)] = strip_tags($value);
    }
}
```

I have added `|| gettype($key) == 'integer'` to your if clause to process integer keys as well.

Comment: If I wanted to pass these all as an object of items into my array create section, IE: 'custom_fields' => array(List of integer id and values)))); Can I do that?

Comment: Absolutely. Rename your form fields appropriately.

Eg. instead of `name="z_subject"`, it will be `name="custom_fields[z_subject]"`